# Keras preprocessing trading data

Tags: python, keras, tf.keras

I have a problem with preprocessing my trading data from .csv so that it fits into sgd model neural network input/output.

I have imported the data using pandas lib but maybe theres a better way to do it?

I need to set column names, data inside needs to be *double* type, and convert it into tf.data.Dataset.

I have 2 data sets: testingdata.csv and trainingdata.csv

each have 4 columns: Open, max, min, close

'Open' column is a forecasting value Y, while 'max', 'min' and 'close' are X Inputs.

[inside my .csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/od6Yg.png)

Also i have no idea what is 'metric' in keras and what metric should i use here

So my questions: what is the best way to do it and how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using pd.read_csv is good way to import `.csv` files

```
 import pandas as pd ​
 ​df= pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

but you need to change column names to custom names so you can do this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv',
                  header=None,
                  names=["open", "max","min","close"],
                  encoding='utf-16')
```

you can see the imported `.csv` file head in dataframe:

```
df.head(5)
```

if you want Converting from `Pandas dataframe` to `TensorFlow Dataset`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
target = df.pop('Open')
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((df.values, target.values))
```

Comment: Thanks for this valuable info, what about the metrics? i dont know which one to choose in this case.

Comment: model evaluation metric for getting accuracy?

Comment: Yes, today i found some info about metrics and from what i got its jsut to show info. So i have chosen mean absolute error to see whats the difference in output(Y1 - Y2)

Comment: it's depending on your task. if you want to evaluate the classification model you can use accuracy, precision, or recall metrics. if you want to evaluate the regression model MSE or MAE metrics can be evaluated.
I think the best metric for you is "Accuracy" if you want to classification between your data.

Comment: As your task is regression, it is good to use MSE (or RMSE) and MAE as metrics. You can also use R2 (coefficient of determination) additionally, although you may need to use sklearn for this purpose.